# Add a rows in a DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I have a landing page that allow to add a new row in my DE.

I fill all the field in my page and when I click on the bouton confirm I don't have any errors message but I don't see the data in the DE.

This is my code:

```
        set @sexe = RequestParameter("gender")
        set @firstname = RequestParameter("firstname")
        set @lastname = RequestParameter("surname")
        set @email = RequestParameter("email")
        set @date1= RequestParameter("date")
        set @tel = RequestParameter("phonenumber")
        set @yy= Substring(@date1,7,4) 
        set @dd= Substring(@date1,4,2)
        set @mm= Substring(@date1,1,2)
        set @i = concat(@mm,'/',@dd,'/',@yy)
        set @date2 = DateParse(@i)

        set @emailmd5 = Uppercase(@email)
        set @UID = MD5(@emailmd5)  

     %%[UPSERTDE("ENT.CUSTOMER_EMAIL_LOT_6",1,"UID_TARGET",@UID,"UPDATE_DATE", NOW(), "FIRSTNAME", @firstname, "SURNAME", @lastname, "EMAIL", @email, "PHONENUMBER",@tel, "GENDER", @sexe, "BIRTHDATE", @date2),"EMAIL_CONTACT", @email]%%
   %%[UPSERTDE("ENT.STOP_EMAIL_LOT_6",1,"UID_TARGET",@UID,"UPDATE_DATE", NOW(), "OPTIN_EMAIL_MARKETING","True", "OPTIN_EMAIL_MARKETING_DATE", NOW(),"OPTIN_SMS", "False", "OPTIN_PARTNER", "False", "OPTIN_PUSH", "False", "NPAI_POSTAL", "False", "NPAI_EMAIL", "False", "NPAI_SMS", "False" )]%%
```

Can you please help me to find out why my row does't appear in my DE knowing that I don't have any error message ?

Comment: Are there any other fields in your DE that you're not addressing in the form? In my experience, if the AMPScript is correct, but you're trying to upsert into a DE with a required field which is not addressed, the form will appear to work but will not actually add any records.

Comment: no there is no other's field in the DE
and the required field is the EMAILADRESS and PHONENUMBER

Comment: `ent.customer_email_lot_6` can you check that you are in a child BU and not the top level one?

Comment: For the DE's, do they have a primary key set? If so, is it just the one 'UID_TARGET'?

Comment: @Data_Kid; you want to say that i must be in the child BU and not the top level one bcause "ent.customer_email_lot_6" is the top one actualy there two "ent.customer_lot_6" i try them both but i doesn't work, Can you confirm that my code is correct?
@Gortonington; the primary key is the  UID_TARGET and is generated by the uppercase of the email adress